# Batch delete BigTable tables and BigQuery datasets

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-bigtable, bigtable

I searched around to find a way to Batch delete BigTable tables and BigQuery datasets (using python's library) without any luck up to now.

Is anyone aware of an efficient way to do that?

I looked into these links but nothing promising :

1. [BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/samples/bigquery-delete-dataset)
2. [BigTable](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/samples/bigtable-hw-delete-table)

Im looking for something similar as this one coming from datastore documentation:

```
from google.cloud import datastore

# For help authenticating your client, visit
# https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started
client = datastore.Client()

keys = [client.key("Task", 1), client.key("Task", 2)]
client.delete_multi(keys)
```

[Batch delete](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/samples/datastore-batch-delete)

Answer (score 1):

I think it's not possible natively, you have to develop your own script.

For example you can configure all the tables to delete, then there are many solutions :

- Develop a `Python` script, loop on the tables to delete and use Python `Bigquery` and `Bigtable` clients : https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/samples/bigquery-delete-dataset
  https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/samples/bigtable-hw-delete-table
- Develop a `shell` script, loop on the tables to delete and use `bq` and `cbt` (from `gcloud` sdk) :
  https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/managing-tables?hl=en#deleting_a_table
  https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/cbt-reference?hl=fr
- If it's possible on your side, you can also use `Terraform` to delete multiple `Bigquery` and `Bigtable` tables, but it's more adapted if you need to manage a state for your infrastructure :
  https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/bigquery_table
  https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/bigtable_table

Comment: thanks for your answer. I have already implemented your first bullet point but I was looking for something more consistent? Are you completely sure that it is not possible for both services?

Comment: I am not completely sure, but I have never seen this kind of example neither in the concerned docs nor in other examples.